# Installing and Using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, gpu, command-prompt

I was really excited about starting to learn tensorflow. But like any other python library, I had to install it first. So I typed out the following pip command in my command prompt:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

But when I did that I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
ERROR: No matching distributions found for tensorflow
```

But when I searched it up, I found out that some websites say that tensorflow requires a GPU, and some websites say that we dont need a GPU to work with tensorflow.

So I thought I could just throw the question up here and maybe one of you could help me get this thing sorted out

Information of my device:

```
Windows Edition : Windows 8.1 Pro
Processor : Intel (R) Core(TM) i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70 GHz 1.70 GHz
Installed memory (RAM) : 4.0 GB
System Type : 64-bit operating system, x-64 Based Processor
```

My computer has no graphics card, but I realized that only linux needs graphics cards to work with tensorflow

Comment: You don't need a gpu to install tensorflow. Could you please look at your version of pip with `pip --version` and `python --version`?

Comment: you need to provide more information such as platform, processor, operating system, and python version.

Comment: I've tried using pip --version, but it says fatal error for some reason. I've also edited the given information about my device on the question section. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

No, Tensorflow works for GPU as well as CPU, see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/). What could be the reason is that you are using Python smaller than 3.6 or bigger than 3.8. In those cases this error is thrown. As of now Tensorflow is only available for Python 3.6-3.8, see link above. If this should not have solved your error, please let me know.

**EDIT**

Like @HenriChab pointed out you can check our Python version with `python --version`

Comment: Ahh yes, my python is Python 3.9.1, I'll try it out right away.....Thank you very much